# Animating div color

Tags: html, css

I have been intensely following this code trying to understand how to animate a border. By tweaking the code, I was able to animate the border color.

However, I WAS NOT able to achieve the effect of animating a div's background color using the same structure of @keyframes

Could someone please help (am not trying for alternate solution, but only want to use the @keyframes)

HTML & CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.green {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  animation: 1s animategreen ease infinite;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@keyframes animategreen {
  to {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess you miss the from value in @keyframes -example https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: since you edited, it works :) , so what is the issue now ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the two animations:

`animation: animation1 1s infinite, animation2 1s infinite`, for example

Here's your code with both working:

```css
.wrapper {
border: 1px solid;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;

}

.green {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;

animation: animategreen 1s infinite, animateBorder 1s infinite;

margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

@keyframes animategreen {
  
    0%     {background-color:red;}
    100%  {background-color:green;}
}

.border {

border: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

@keyframes animateBorder {
to {

border-top-color: rgba(0,0,102,1);
border-right-color: rgba(0,0,102,1);
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,102,1);
border-left-color: rgba(0,0,102,1);
border-top-width: 3px;
border-right-width: 3px;
border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-left-width: 3px;
border-top-color: rgba(51,0,204,1);
border-right-color: rgba(51,0,204,1);
border-bottom-color: rgba(51,0,204,1);
border-left-color: rgba(51,0,204,1);    

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="green border">
</div>
</div>
```

Sorry about the CSS mess, I made it fast :)

Comment: ok thanks. now how will you edit this code so that it animates ONLY the border?

Comment: just remove the background color animation (
`animation: animateBorder 1s infinite;`) or use the keyframes to use the same `background-color` (kinda hacky)

Comment: or how about if I remove animategreen 1s infinite from .green ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Using just `animation: animateBorder 1s infinite;` will only set the border animation i.e removing  `animategreen 1s infinite`

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer helped you, please upvote it an accept it as the answer.

Comment: Click the triangle above the 0 (http://i.imgur.com/rrK50gp.png), and below the down triangle you should see the icon (http://i.imgur.com/BnXtvD3.png) to accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can have only one animation for each, here you set background to green, then you override it with border, both animation should be mixed

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.green {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  animation: 1s animategreen ease infinite;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  animation: 1s animateBorder ease-in infinite;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
@keyframes animateBorder {
  to {
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 102, 1);
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 102, 1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 102, 1);
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 102, 1);
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-top-color: rgba(51, 0, 204, 1);
    border-right-color: rgba(51, 0, 204, 1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(51, 0, 204, 1);
    border-left-color: rgba(51, 0, 204, 1); 
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green border">
  </div>
</div>
```